# One to many forms need advice

Tags: vb.net, forms, linklabel

Hi Guys just want to ask advice regarding a form inside a control panel.

Its actually a ebook kind of program with table of contents.. See my screenshot below

[image]

On the left side are labels that when i click contents will be shown in the right panel.

Notes: Ive made 3 forms 1st form is the screenshot 2nd form has its own text contents and 3rd is another example below is my code:

```
Private Sub LinkLabel1_LinkClicked(sender As Object, e As LinkLabelLinkClickedEventArgs) Handles LinkLabel1.LinkClicked
    Dim f3 As New Form3 With {.TopLevel = False, .AutoSize = False, .FormBorderStyle = FormBorderStyle.None}
    f3.Parent = Panel1
    Form2.Hide()
    f3.Show()

End Sub

Private Sub LinkLabel2_LinkClicked(sender As Object, e As LinkLabelLinkClickedEventArgs) Handles LinkLabel2.LinkClicked
    Dim f As New Form2 With {.TopLevel = False, .AutoSize = False, .FormBorderStyle = FormBorderStyle.None}
    f.Parent = Panel1
    Form.Hide()
    f.Show()
```

Cant seem to work this out. Thanks you!

Comment: Form.Hide() does not do what you think it does.  This is in general broken code, you must dispose the previous form object.  While Panel1.Controls.Count > 0: Panel1.Controls(0).Dispose: End While

Comment: I don't see a question here

Comment: Hi Sir, sorry for the confusion. I tired @hansPassant advice to use dispose and it works. TYVM this is my assignment. Now can i ask final question? How to i do a simple table of contents? For example "+ Chapter 1" wherein when i press the "+" button sub-chapters will show on bullets? Is this possible? Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the form as a control to the panel instead

```
Dim f As New Form2 With {.TopLevel = False, .AutoSize = False, .FormBorderStyle = FormBorderStyle.None}
Panel1.Controls.Add(f)
f.Show()
```